# Regex expression exceptions in subsetting data with grepl

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset data in R by certain characters in a field and cannot find the correct regex logic to get what I need. I need to subset records for which the ID contains either:

- Just "AB"
- "AB" and "ABC"
- But NOT fields with ONLY "ABC"

These patterns fall within any part of the field (beginning, middle, end) in this data set and have no certain separators.

Example dataset TEST:

```
 Record     ID                value
 1          blueAB_ABC        7
 2          green_ABCblue    9
 3          ABC_green         45
 4          green_AB          23
 5          CD_red            45
```

So for this example I would want to subset records 1 and 4.

I've gotten as far as returning those with just AB and excluding ABC, but cannot seem to find the proper regex to get all with "AB" and potentially "ABC".

```
AB_set <- subset(TEST, grepl("*AB", ID) & !grepl("*ABC", ID) )

 Record     ID                value
 4          green_AB          23
```

What I'm hoping to get:

```
 Record     ID                value
 1          blueAB_ABC       7
 4          green_AB          23
```

EDIT: Just to clarify, I updated the dataset to show that the pattern in question may fall next to other characters than an underscore, or may not necessarily occur at the beginning/end (as previously noted, "no certain separators").

Comment: The `*` refers to any character

Comment: Apologies for not making my data set more specific, but I noted that the AB could be surrounded by something other than an underscore, which is why I was looking to exclude "ABC"--the only instance I don't want to match if it occurs alone.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this by specifying that "AB" should be surrounded by either underscore or a word boundary.

```
 df[grepl("(\\b|_)AB(\\b|_)", df$ID),]
  Record          ID value
1      1 blue_AB_ABC     7
4      4    green_AB    23
```

Comment: By "word boundary" do you mean that AB could be surrounded by another letter? If so, the issue of ABC occurrences still stands...

Comment: @user2479802 "word boundary" means any character that is _not_ a word character, underscores are also considered word characters, so they need to be added as an alternative in the regex. It is a "zero-length match", so instead of matching a character, it matches a position

Comment: As @user pointed out, `"ABC" is not needed because "AB" is always required to be matched.` Requiring a word boundary allows AB to be at the beginning or end or next to blanks or punctuation, but there must be an instance of AB with no other letters next to it.

Comment: I failed to include an example in my dataset where AB could fall next to something other than a start/end/underscore (I just said "no certain separators"). Something like "blueAB_green" or "879AB_red" could appear in the dataset, so how do I account for this?

Comment: Can there be ABD? Is it AB with no other letters, but numbers are OK?

Comment: It is possible that AB may appear next to other letters (e.g. ABD) in addition to numbers (e.g. AB765).

Comment: What is an easy why to restructure this to look for AB if it appears next to numbers? Letters are less of a concern. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. Is it the case that you are _only_ excluding AB next to a capital letter? AB next to anything else is OK?

Comment: I just made a discovery in my dataset which might make things easier. The "ABC" I mentioned will always proceed X (i.e. will always be "XABC"). So I need to match entries that include "AB" not preceded by X, but these entries may ALSO include "XABC". I just want to avoid matching entries that contain ONLY "XABC". Hope this makes it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

"ABC" is not needed because "AB" is always required to be matched. The following matches AB only if it is surrounded by underscore or it starts or ends an `ID`:

```
AB_set <- subset(TEST, grepl("(^|_)AB(_|$)", TEST$ID))
```

**Result:**

```
  Record          ID value
1      1 blue_AB_ABC     7
4      4    green_AB    23
```

**Data:**

```
TEST = structure(list(Record = 1:5, ID = structure(c(2L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
3L), .Label = c("ABC_green", "blue_AB_ABC", "CD_red", "green_AB", 
"green_ABC_blue"), class = "factor"), value = c(7L, 9L, 45L, 
23L, 45L)), .Names = c("Record", "ID", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```